# Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php

Weird parser errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: template::$param in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 37

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined property: template::$param in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 37

Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 37
```

Code:

```
public function newParam($trans, $value) {
    $this->param['{' . $trans . '}'] = $value;
}

public function getParam($content) {
    $content = str_replace(
        array_keys($this->param), 
        array_values($this->param), 
        $content
    );

    return $content;
}
```

Please note that this isn't any existing parser.

Comment: It appears that for some reason, your `$this->param` is `null`.

Comment: In addition to what you have here, we need to see the code where you are actually instantiating this class and calling `getParam()`.  It would seem that `$this->param` is not initialized at the time `getParam()` is called. Is the `$param` property initialized as a class property, as in `public $param = array();`?

Comment: Please post the entire class declaration. I'm particularly interested in what `$this->param` contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init your "param":

```
function __construct() {
  $this->param = array();
}
```

You may also see the [PHP Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax

An existing array can be modified by explicitly setting values in it.

This is done by assigning values to the array, specifying the key in brackets. The key can also be omitted, resulting in an empty pair of brackets ([]).

$arr[key] = value;
$arr[] = value;
// key may be an integer or string
// value may be any value of any type
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure fideloper/proxy version is 4.0 for laravel >= 5.5

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "**fideloper/proxy**": **"^4.0"**,
```